# After running installation of Anaconda 2.7 for windows 10, Anaconda prompt not responding

Tags: windows, python-2.7, anaconda

I'm unable to find Anaconda navigator. Also I can see anaconda prompt but that seems to have problem as it doesn't respond to any command. And there seems to be problem with some `activation.bat` file.
 Is there some general issue with anaconda for windows 10?
[Please see the link for screenshot of Anaconda prompt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKkRl.png)

Comment: Please do not post code in screenshots. Search engines cannot index that text (so no one else could find this question) and blind users cannot read it at all. Please copy and paste the text of the error into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the problem was, but it worked just fine after couple of re installation. I wonder if many people are facing the same issue for windows 10.